# Excel/VBA performance

Tags: performance, excel, vba

I have a certain set of formula in Range("E10001:E20000") which i'd like to copy to Columns("F:CZ") total 1M cells. Options:

1. Range("E10001:E20000").Copy
   Range("F10001:CZ20000").PasteSpecial xlPasteAll
2. Range("F10001:CZ20000").formula = Range("E10001:E20000").formula
3. Range("E10001:CZ20000").fillRight
4. Range("E10001:CZ20000").Select
   followed by Ctrl+R in Excel

At the end, to make the sheet light, i replace formulae with Values, 
Range("F10001:CZ20000").Value = Range("F10001:CZ20000").Value

What i notice is that Option 4 is way faster than the rest. Can anybody explain the performance penalties in the first 3 options. Note, i'm unfamiliar with time functions and measured physically using seconds clock.

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: **Do not use shortcuts with the SendKeys method!**
Longer answer: Shortcuts can lead to unexpected results, in my local settings "^r" would (start to) insert a table.
Feel free to use a timer with starttime = Now at the beginning of your code and

```
timetaken = Now - starttime
MsgBox (Hour(timetaken) & ":" & Minute(timetaken) & ":" & Second(timetaken))
```

to measure the performance though.
As a rule of thumb, your time is worth way more than system time and corrupting your data by accidentally sending the wrong set of instructions is **never** worth the risk.
Your operation with 2 × 10,000 cells is not worth optimising.

Comment: While i generally agree that human time is more imp, this is part of a huge reusable solution i am building. Not just computation, but even the input and output are of size 100colx.2Mrows. :) It is only after optimizing design, algorithm, & implementing basic logic, i'm looking at code performance.